# iOS 7 keep iOS 6 UI

Tags: ios, ios7

I have design that is correspond to iOS 6. I know that iOS 7 has many differences in UI, but can I keep iOS 6 UI (like back button, tab bars, alerts) and at the same time let users install app on theirs devices with iOS 7.

So I mean even if user run on iOS 7 the UIControl back button from navigation bar does not change its appearance and stay with iOS 6 design.

Comment: You should have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627599/when-ios-7-is-launch-will-all-application-that-is-build-for-ios-6-look-well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you keep and build app in IOS SDK 6 and Xcode 4.6 and then install app in IOS 7, it will keep your old GUI but some part will convert to IOS 7 GUI such as `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `xcode 4.6` not `xcode 4.5` minor error but still.

Comment: Yes it will any xcode version which is before XCODE 5.0...

Comment: So do you think the round rect button will be displayed on devices with installed iOS 7?

Comment: I have not tried round rect button but you can try it will simply add one button and load app in IOS 7 device....

Comment: No, I think iOS 7 changes it regardless. I made an application with Xcode 4.6 before iOS 7 came out, then once I installed iOS 7 on my device, all the buttons were changed. So now I just see floating text instead of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only with xCode 4.

If you want to do it in xCode 5 - you need to use custom graphics so UI will look similar on both iOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

I use two versions of XCode, one with the old SDK and one with the new! If you create the app with iOS6 elements, that is the way it will look on all iPhones. Except for a couple of things like the UIAlertView and UIActionsSheet, just like kokx explained.

Comment: so I mean even round rect button will be shown on the devices with iOS 7? am I right?

Comment: I am not quite sure what round rect button means, but if it means the standard buttons for iOS6 then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use legacyUI method. Just put the below code in your Appdelegate

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"UIUseLegacyUI"]
```

Comment: If you're not going through the app store you can use this. This is part of a Private API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020284/using-ios-6-theme-for-ios-7-app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179874/how-to-still-use-ios6-ui-in-ios-7 Apps that use this code will be rejected from the app store. -1 as your answer doesn't tell the user of this information