# Is it possible to use old styled controls for iOS on xCode 5.0?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

The new look of iOS 7 is too different from previous versions.
Is it possible to use old styled controls on iOS 7 on xCode 5.0?

Comment: If you run it under < iOS 7, then it will use the old controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's based on the SDK you're building against, so if you build against the iOS 6.X SDK instead of the iOS 7 SDK it should use the iOS 6.X look and feel. There's some information on how to do that here: [Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)

It's non-trivial though, and means you can't use any of the features introduced in the iOS 7 SDK. As long as you're comfortable with that then it's a good choice, the other thing to do would be to create your own variants of the iOS components with the same look that you want, which is a large amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but you need to copy the SDK from the previous xCode, I have both (xCode 4, xCode 5)

Copy this

```
/Applications/Xcode 4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
```

to

```
/Applications/Xcode 5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

and copy this:

```
/Applications/Xcode 4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
```

to

```
/Applications/Xcode 5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

and, in your project change the "Base SDK" (on Build Settings) to iOS 6.1 instead of latest