# UISegmentControl stays in iOS 7 look, when using iOS 6 SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to have the old iOS 6 look in my app, even if it runs on iOS 7. Therefore, I'm building with iOS 6 SDK. Described here: [Is it possible to use old styled controls for iOS on xCode 5.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769417/is-it-possible-to-use-old-styled-controls-for-ios-on-xcode-5-0?lq=1).

Now it looks like this under iOS7:

[image: iOS 6 look under iOS 7]

Problem: You see, NavigationBar and barButtons switch back to the old look of iOS 6. But the segmentControl doesn't.

Question: Why doesn't the segmentControl switch back to iOS 6 look? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to crate two xib per class.
1>Earlier ios 7 version
2>Ios 7 later

so you need to crate ios 7 segment bar as image and before ios 7 segment bar as it is.you need to call this xib based on it's version.