# Xcode 5 "Missing compiler spec LLVM 4.2" error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, xcode4.6

I am currently trying to build my project in Xcode 5. Build fails with error:

**Dependency Analysis Error:** 
`missing compiler specification <XCCompilerSpecification:`  *Some memory address here* `:'com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42':MISSING:Default> for file`

for all code files in project.

The project used to be built in Xcode 4.6 with LLVM 4.2 and now Xcode 5 only supports LLVM 5. So there is obviously something related to that here.

I have set the build settings in Xcode 5 to use LLVM 5 and the build still fails for the same reason. Has anyone encountered this before and know how to stop Xcode 5 from looking for LLVM 4.2 which it no longer supports?

This question is as a result of [iOS 6 vs 7 appearance build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071254/ios-6-vs-7-appearance-build-settings)

Comment: what happens when you do a clean and then rebuild?

Comment: Cleaning the project fails due to the same problems. The memory addresses stay constant throughout the same run of Xcode. Relaunching Xcode changes the memory address.

Comment: Are you using some custom linker flags and such?

Comment: @SimonGermain, I am not using custom linker flags. Although I tried to remove a framework search path for the Reveal App framework. Now there is only a $(inherited) _non-recursive_ under Framework Search Paths and Library Search Paths. The build and clean actions still fail.

Comment: What's the compiler set to in the project settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something similar in an old project I have today. What happened is that there was a subproject in my project and that one wasn't set to llvm5.

You may want to do a search in your directory to find a file specifying llvm 4.2, like such:

```
MyMac:~/path/to/my/project $ grep -rHin llvm *

MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:334: GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42;
MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:348: GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42;
```

If that's the case, try updating that subproject or removing it altogether, see if you can at least clean your build.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I forgot about an older build rule I had which referenced LLVM GCC 4.2. Removing said build rule fixed the build errors.

Comment: The other reason is a build rule that still uses gcc 4.2, @see comment [#19116626](#19116626)

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem and I found that under Project-> Build Rules, gcc compiler was being used which no longer exist with Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

first, if you use virtual machine, maybe it's the problem when it doesn't have grant to access into your project
if not check your file Maybe you miss any file?