# Xcode 5 shows the same device twice

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode5

Ever since my team switched from Xcode 4 to 5, this weird bug shows up, that:

When we connect the iPhone/iPod touch to the macs, the device will be shown as two devices as deployment candidate.
Both have the same device name correctly displayed but if we run our app on the 1st one, sometimes a segue will cause a crash whereas the same segue will work fine on the 2nd one.

This issue occurs on all of our devices on different macs: iPod Touch 5, iPhone 4s, iPhone 5 with iOS 6 and 7

So my questions are, why are there 2 of the same device, and further, how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you installed iOS 6.1 sdk in XCode 5?

Comment: @rakmoh Yes, we moved iOS6.1 SDK from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5 by copy-paste.

Comment: It's most likely a bug related to having the 6.1 and 7.0 SDKs side-by-side like that in Xcode 5. It happens on my system as well.

Answer (score 33):

as @Petesh states, this is due to adding the 6.1 SDK to xCode 5.  Additionally, one of the devices will run with iOS 6.1 visual styles while the other will run with 7.0 styles.  Sadly you can't tell the difference which will run with the 6.1 styles and which will run with the 7.0 styles.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there anything we can do about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use symbolic link to sdk 6.1. I have deleted symbolic link and made copy of sdk 6.1 into xcode. Crashes were eliminated after this actions.

Comment: How exactly do I proceed this? If I did this, would I still have the ability to create new project with iOS 6.1 sdk?

Comment: Yes. There are 2 ways to work with iOS 6.1. Making symbolic link to sdk 6.1 causes crashes for me. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)

Comment: I copied SDK 6.1 into Xcode and yet I have this problem also.

Comment: Removing simlinks to sdk6.2 from xcode5 helped me resolve this issue with xcode5.