# Errors in AFNetworking 2.2.1

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I added the folders AFNetworking and UIKit+AFNetworking manually to my project.

When I tried to compile (iOS6.1) I get the following errors in AFSecurifyPolicy.m

```
/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.m:233:5: Implicit declaration of function 'SecTrustSetPolicies' is invalid in C99  

/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.m:271:44: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'firstObject'
```

Trying iOS7.0 doesn't help. Anyone has any idea when I'm getting these errors?

**Update**: Did a clean and rebuild and its building now.

**Update 2**: The error is back. It happens when I connect a device and builds for it. Happens for both iOS 6 and 7 devices. Building for simulator is fine. Any ideas?

Attached some information below:

Xcode: Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)
[image: Arch]
[image: language]

Comment: consider posting the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Which xcode version do you use ? Which compiler and language version is set ?
No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'firstObject has been added quite a while ago now...
And consider moving to cocoa pods, it's great and might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed there are two devices of the same name when I connected the device.
Only the second one builds.
Found from the solution [Xcode 5 shows the same device twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054395/xcode-5-shows-the-same-device-twice) that it is caused by SDK6.1. So I removed that.
Now Xcode only shows one device, and it builds fine.

Just a side note, deployment target is set to iOS 6.1. So far its able to build and run fine. Have not tested its functionality yet though.