# Xamarin.iOS Target iOS 6 SDK

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, ios7, xamarin

We have upgraded to XCode 5 and Xamarin.iOS 7.x, but have one app we are not quite ready to support iOS 7 for yet.

Is there a way to target the iOS 6.0 SDK, and compile the app so that it has the old iOS 6 keyboard, etc.?

We tried changing the settings in iOS Build->SDK Version, and we can change it when targeting the simulator, but the option doesn't exist for AhHoc or AppStore builds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode ships with several simulator SDK but only one device SDK. So you need to install an older version of Xcode. E.g. installing Xcode 4.6 will give you the 6.1 SDK).

Both versions can coexists side-by-side if you rename the existing one before installing the 2nd.

Be sure to have XS points to the Xcode you want to use (it's not a project specific setting).

Comment: What do I do if I upgraded in-place? Only way to get an old XCode from developer.apple.com?

Comment: Should not be a problem. Just rename your Xcode to `Xcode5.app`, then download 4.6 from developer.apple.com and install it. I used to have 4.2 (in /Developer/), 4.3, 4.4, 4.5 and 4.6 before updating my laptop to ML.

Comment: Well, I can't get it to download... site keeps failing at about 50%. Let you know when it works.

Comment: I had some great luck with [linking the older SDK into the newer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18957939/48700) so I could switch between them in Xamarin Studio as needed. This does make it a project setting, though it would probably be an interesting error on someone's machine who hadn't done the same process. That said, [Apple announced all submissions after February 1, 2014 need to use the iOS 7 SDK](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a#top).