# Use iOS 5 Simulator in XCode 5?

Tags: ios5, xcode5

It seems that XCode 5 only comes with the iOS 6 and 7 simulators. Is there a way to use the iOS 5 simulator with XCode 5?

Answer (score 27):

If you're using Xcode 5 under OS X v10.8 then if you go to Preferences -> Downloads you should see the 5.0 and 5.1 simulators available under 'Components'. You can download and install directly from there.

If you're using Xcode 5 under OS X v10.9 then the iOS 5 simulator is no longer available.

In terms of lessons to learn, Apple did exactly the same thing with iOS 4 and the transition from OS X v10.7 to v10.8. So it's not unreasonable to expect that from now on Apple is going to supply simulators only for the version of iOS that was current when that OS X came out and the one before it.

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't showing - only the 6.0 and 6.1 simulators are. Anything special I have to do to make them appear?

Comment: Update - according to a post on the iOS developer forums, the iOS 5 simulator only appears under Mountain Lion, not Mavericks - are you running 10.8? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm a registered iOS developer only. As I'm not a registered Mac developer I'm not sure I have access to — and definitely don't concern myself with — beta copies of OS X. If Apple has removed the iOS 5 simulator under Mavericks then you're probably out of luck; I don't think anybody ever managed to get the iOS 4 simulator to work under Mountain Lion.

Comment: @colen Do you have a link to that post on the iOS developer forums?

Comment: I have this problem too. Installed a fresh copy of Mavericks and Xcode 5 and only 6.x and above are available for download.

Answer (score 7):

Since Mavericks and Xcode 5.1, iOS5 Simulator is now gone :(

Seems Apple want us to focus on iOS7 and iOS6. (iOS5 now holds only < 1 to 5 % total on active AppStore devices)

Answer (score 4):

While there is no 5.1 simulator under Mavericks, you still can connect up an old iPad1 to do your testing.

Answer (score 2):

Additional Simulators can be installed from `Xcode -> Preference -> Downloads -> Components`

[image: Screenshot for downloading simulator]

However, in case of Xcode 5.x iOS 5 simulator cannot be installed since Mavericks doesn’t allows it.

[image: Apple document for Xcode 5 Screenshot]

[Apple document for Xcode 5 link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't technically answer your question, but that's how I do it in practice:

You can have Xcode 4 and 5 installed simultaneously on the system. Xcode4 does have support for iOS 5. You just need to download Xcode4 from the [downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) and rename the app before installing to the system (so that you don't copy it over Xcode 5).

Edit: this solution is not working anymore. Used to work but currently crashes for me.

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, even Xcode 4 does not support iOS 5 simulator.

Comment: You're right Legoless, I have the simulator but it crashes when I run it. Used to work, but a recent update might have broken it.

Comment: Mavericks kernel is changed and it doesn't run iOS 5 simulator anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the old version of XCode you can try giving a symbolic link as explained in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957939/2415693

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run iOS 5.0 simulator using Xcode 5 on Lion. But after upgrade to Maverick it didn't work the same way it did on Lion. May be there is a way, but not the same as before...

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Mavericks, but I have Mountain Lion as a virtual partition under Parallels Desktop. Under Xcode 5.0.2 downloads the iOS 5.0 and 5.1 simulators are showing up, and I've downloaded them, but sadly I can't seem to select them when running an app.

The 5.1 simulator as such runs fine if I select in manually, it's just that I can't seem to deploy apps on it from Xcode, even though I'm setting my deployment target to 5.1.1.

To satisfy my curiosity I've also got Mountain Lion running from an external hard disk (without the virtual machine) and I get the same results: no deploying apps from Xcode 5 to iOS 5.1.1