# Can't start the iPhone Simulator with specified version

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, ios-simulator

After upgrading `XCode 5.0 to 5.1`  I can't run my app on `iOS 7.0 and lower version simulator`, its giving me error `Can't start the iPhone Simulator with specified version` even if i run in iOS 7.1 simulator.
How can i run my app in iOS 7.0 and lower version simulator?

Comment: Have you downloaded the prior versions of of the simulator???

Comment: ya i am doing this..but not working

Comment: Set Deployment target to lower version in project target under General Tab.

Comment: ya i also do this but its not work

Comment: this post might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281739/use-ios-5-simulator-in-xcode-5

Answer (score 0):

Try to Uninstall xcode and install it again. this might help !!