# where do additional iOS simulators download to?

Tags: ios, xcode

I *Know* i downloaded an additional legacy 3.5" non-retina simulator for XCode 5:
but it does not come up as a choice in the Hardware>Device Menu while the Retina simulator running.

I get it running on my laptop, but not on my main machine, so i figure if i can find the plugin or package i can transfer a copy. I'm two weeks away from refeshing my internet download limits so if i can avoid another 640Mb it would be nice. Anyway I'm sure i downloaded it on the main machine as well, in my user account.

I've looked here

> Applications/Xcode5/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/

but that's not the whole of it

and

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/ as per other SO answers

also `HD/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins`

but `User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/` just has runtime data

In the Interim I take my screenshots at @2x and scale it down in GraphicConverter, but that's a right royal pain. ( why not do it on the laptop i hear you ask? Answer is I'll be giving it to a family member for uni next year and i'm weaning myself off it )

the question is where so i can copy it over?

Comment: I should add i am running XCode 4.6 and 5.0 on both machines, and showing contents of each package and going from there lands me at a simulator. But i hear warning bells if i think about copying those over back and forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have version 4.6 of XCode you can try giving a symbolic link as explained in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957939/2415693

Comment: lotsa reading there and in following the links further. I'll consider it answered,, as variations of the solution given seems to be the most common. Its not exactly my situation as most seem to want to see how it looks in iOS-6. I'm happy to have iOS7 as the project base. For `7 users on and older phone another workaround I have is to physically connect my wife's iPhone 4 running iOS7 and email the screenGrabs until my Download limit gets renewed.