# update existing app without making changes for IOS 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store, ios7, app-store-connect

I have an existing app inside the appstore. And now I need to update it. When I build and run it from `XCode5` on my `IOS7` phone the layout is completely messed up. But when I reinstall it from the `appstore` I get back my old good looking layout.

Now I was wondering when I do a minor bug fix inside my app and I upload it to the appstore. People who are going to update/download it, are they getting the bad `IOS7` layout that I get when I ran it from `xcode` ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can still submit updates to your app with Xcode 4.6.3. Or you can take SDK6 from Xcode 4.6.3 and use it in Xcode 5. What will happen is, people will see the legacy UI which they saw in iOS6.

Comment: FYI, using iOS SDK 6 with Xcode 5 may still result in undesired behaviour; see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884272/is-it-possible-to-build-iphoneos6-1-projects-in-xcode-5-preserving-the-behaviou

Comment: Yes, you can. Download from developer.apple.com and run side by side.

Comment: @Greg taking old SDK worked for me on device but not on simulator.