# How can I build for iOS 6 with Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have already downloaded the new Xcode 5.0, but I wanted to build an app for iOS 6...

How can I do that from Xcode 5.0? Or do I need to have a version of Xcode 4 installed so I can do that?

Xcode does let me change the deployment target as the screen below:
[image: deployment targer]

But it doesn't let me use a older Base SDK

[image]

Comment: Change the Deployment target to iOS 6

Comment: Xcode 5 is backward compatible. by default it support iOS 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you need to download the older Xcode you want to build for.
After that, you copy the .sdk in the folder of the older Xcode `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/platform/SDK`

and paste it in the same folder, but now, from the Xcode 5.0

Now, you should be able to choose between all the .sdk installed on that folder under the "Build settings" tab of your project, under Base SDK.

Comment: -1 this results in an unsupported configuration of Xcode and is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: +1 this worked very well for me.

Comment: Yes, This worked for me as well... Ton of thanks...

Comment: This is the wrong answer, and will not work after February 1.

Answer (score 8):

Just set the Deployment Target to iOS6, in the configuration of the project:

[image]

Comment: He might also need to download the older sdk's or has apple fixed that you don't need to do that anymore

Comment: You can deploy for an earlier target than your SDK as long as you don't use any APIs that were introduced in the newer version.

Comment: Where is that screen you put? I think i still need to download the older SDK to be able to change de base SDK right?

Comment: If you want to compile using the iOS6 SDK you'll need the previous XCode

Comment: @AlexandreLins just use the iOS 7 SDK and set your deployment target to iOS 6.  That's all you need to do.

Comment: @DaveDeLong setting the deployment target to iOS 6 is only going to make possible for people with older iOS version to download the app. But, if i build it with the iOS 7 SDK it will come with the new features of iOS 7, like the transparent top bar, which I don't want it to have for now...That's why I need to build it with iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: @AlexandreLins ... you only get transparent bars if you run it on iOS 7.  If you run a 7-built app on iOS 6, it looks just like an iOS 6 app.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Yeah...that's right, but i don't want it to appear even if the user is running iOS 7...not for now at least...that is why I need to build it for iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: HE deliberately specified in the question that it IS NOT what he wants.

Comment: HE edited the question after my answer