# App submission from xCode 4.62 targeting iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am still using xCode 4.62 targeting min iOS 6.0. This is currently working for both iOS 6.0 and 7.0. When we try to build with xCode 5.0, we found some issues with the UI in iOS 7.0.

We would like to continue to use xCode 4.62. Anyone with pointers on official Apple website about when they will stop supporting xCode 4.62 and min iOS 6.0 support?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store policy, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a

Comment: May be this will help
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917740/how-can-i-build-for-ios-6-with-xcode-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have until 1 February 2014. After that, apps must be built using the 7.0 SDK, which means Xcode 5+. This was emailed to all registered developers.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a) (via desdenova's comment):