# How to make a IOS 7 App build with Base SDK (IOS 7) appear on IOS 7 as a IOS 6 App

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

Sorry for the complicated title!
But my APP was developer with Xcode 4 for IOS 6. I now migrated to IOS 7 and XCODE 5.

When I build the APP now and set the deployment target to IOS 5 my app looks as always great on IOS 5 or 6 phones. But on IOS 7 it is all messed up. So as long as I have to support IOS 5... Is there any flag that I can set to make Xcode produce an binary which is fully IOS 6 comapatible on a IOS 7 device?

Comment: u have to make changes to support ios7 and it depends on your application how much you have to change

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19020449/983912

Comment: The proper thing to do is to make your app look like an iOS 7 app when run under iOS 7. That is what users want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xcode 5. You have to download ios 6 sdk and just add it to xcode 5 and select it as base sdk for your project. You can follow the instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5) on how to do this.

Comment: thank you. I just did as you suggested. I nom compile with Sdk 6.1 Allthough the app looks better it is still not the same as before. I now installed XCode 4 again. And can now at least produce for phones running IOS 7 a good looking App with Xcode 4.

Answer (score 0):

iOS6 SDK isn't available in XCode 5.

You could download an older version of Xcode from the developer portal.
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

Then install it under a different name on your mac just by renaming the app. 
For instance Xcode-legacy

Comment: You can install older iOS SDKs under xcode 5 without issues. Check the below answers. No need to have two xcode installations.

Comment: I know, but Xcode 4 uses LLVM 2.0 while Xcode 5 compiles with LLVM 5.0. If you really want to reproduce the situation as it was before Xcode 5, you do need an older version of Xcode

Comment: @Thomas your right. I included the 6.1 Base Sdk in Xcode 5 and still there were differences to the Xcode 4.3 produced app. So I reverted back for now to Xcode 4.3

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Xcode-> click show package content go to following path

Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer

if you see only iPhoneOS7.0.sdk that means you don't have lower SDK copy lower SDK their..

Change Base SDK from project setting.

This should keep on allowing you to build your applications with the iOS 6 style UI, at the same time allowing you to use Xcode 5.