# How to deploy xamarin ios app with SDK Version 5.0 to use old theme (not iOS 7 Theme) in visual studio 2013

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

Hello everyone I have a legacy xamarin.iOS project (built with 5.0 SDK) now i need to update some things without changing the look of the app.

After some research how to get the older SDKs to show up in the SDK Version dropdown in Visual Studio 2013 I finally got to select the 5.0 SDK (I also changed the Deployment Target to 5.0)

But when I deploy the app to my iPhone 5S running iOS 7.1.1. i get the iOS 7 Theme

Is there any way to get the app to use the old theme? (If I download the app from the store it works with the old theme, so there should be some way)

By the way on my research I read this article [Using iOS 6 theme for iOS 7 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020284/using-ios-6-theme-for-ios-7-app)

Is it true that I cant upload apps using an older SDK? Even for app updates?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submission to the Apple store requires that the product be compiled with the most recent released Tools (Xcode 5.1.1 at this point) and compiled with the most recent SDK (Currently 7.1)