# Use xcode5 develop ios6 programe, the view's origin Y

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have a app develop under ios6 and does not release for now, yesterday I'm upgrade my xcode to 5, and I'm try use it develop my old app, everything is ok, but some of my controller's base view's origin Y is 0 for now, it means these views are just below the status bar, and navigation bar over it. I don't want to add 44 to all of the controllers base view's frame origin y.

Does someone know about this, or do I needs to switch my xcode to 4

Comment: Does not duplicate, @gWiz answered right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you have two options:

1) Install the iOS6.1 SDK into Xcode5. The easiest way to do this is copy the ios6 SDK from Xcode 4 found in: `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/` and paste it in the same place inside Xcode5 app. (See more details here: [Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)). After that you can use 'Base SDK: iOS6.1'.

2) Make all your navigation controllers opaque instead of translucent. For example in Interface Builder, uncheck the Translucent check box after selecting your navigation bar.