# iOS 6 simulators in Xcode 5

Tags: ios7, ios6, xcode5, ios-simulator

I have installed Xcode5 with iOS 7 SDK but I am not able to test iOS 6 simulator or prior in Xcode 5.

I have tried *Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components* but it doesn't show an option for downloading the iOS 6 simulator.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5

Answer (score 59):

Open *Preferences* (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) then go to the *Downloads* tab. There you can download the simulator for the iOS you want.
[image]

This can be found where you choose the simulator and then click on "more simulators..."

Comment: Mine does not present this option

Comment: Jesse - I guess, it might be internet problem.

Comment: This option did not work for me. I selected the ones to download, pressed check and install now, and ios 6.0 was 20% done when I walked away from my computer for a bathroom break. I came back 5 minutes later and saw that it had made negative progress -- it was now only about 5% done (and stuck). The chance that someone touches my computer in that time is 0.00001%. Now, when I try to install it, the progress bar is stuck at 0%. I am using xcode 5.0.2

Comment: it also doesn't present those option like that, so I cannot download the 6.0. Can anyone tell me why it so?

Answer (score 12):

To add on to Joan Cardona answer, the "More Simulators" option will only be available if your deployment target is below 7.0 .

Target -> Project Name -> Under 'Deployment Target'

Change your Deployment Target to anything lower than 7.0. The "More Simulators" option will then be visible.

Comment: While I haven't checked that this works, it is probably the answer that should be marked as correct.  Joan provides a good answer, however since Vinay stated in the original question that the option isn't there for him; your answer is the one that stands out as being from someone who has actually read the question.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Xcode and it's under Xcode > Preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Still we can use ios 6 simulator in xcode 5.1.

> If you cant see iOS 6 simulator in downloads. Try this one,
>
> download **xcode 4** sdk and copy the **ios 6 simulator sdk** from xcode4,
>   [Application->xcode 4 ->contents->developer->platforms->iphone
>   simulator platform->developer->sdk folder.]
>
> And paste **ios 6 simulator** sdk to **xcode 5**, [Application->xcode5->
>   contents->developer->platforms->iphonesimulator
>   platform->developer->sdk folder]

I followed this steps and got ios 6 simulator,. see below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved it by closing Xamarin studio.

Makes sense in hindsight...

Answer (score 0):

*Please click on active scheme and select "More Simulator"*,**There you can download the simulator for the iOS**.
   Please check this screen short

[image]