# How to deploy iPad app for iOS 6.1 from Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I am new to iOS. With iOS 7 release I am struggling to find how to target my app for previous versions but building from new iOS 7.

I do not know if at all this is possible. but iOS has changed app UI totally, but can not do all change now.  So I have been told to build it on new version but target should be for old, so that no UI changes to be done.

Something like building from Xcode 5 but iOS should be 6.1. I do have both Xcode running on my Mac.

If I open both it shows: Xcode 5 - iOS 7, Xcode 4.6 - iOS 6.1. How can I use Xcode 5 to target iOS 6.1?

Comment: You can set Deployment Target to iOS 6.1 in Project Settings

Comment: Downvoting questions without giving any reason is not helpful for the user.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't deploy only for iOS6.x using xcode 5, but you can deploy for iOS7 and iOS6, setting the deployment target ad Raptor said.
If you want to deploy only for iOS6 you can download the old xcode 4.6.3 from apple site and make the procedure from there.

Comment: AFAIK Apple rejects all apps which are not built for iOS 7.

Comment: @HAS That's incorrect for now. One can target SDK6 (even using Xcode 5) and it will be accepted on the AppStore **for now**.

Comment: @Leo Thanks for the info! I read that somewhere but can't find it, so I stay corrected!

Comment: Apple does its best to hide it, so people don't do it. :-) One has to acquire SDK6 from an Xcode 4.6 installation, in order to build for 6.1. But it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is `How to build iOS app with iOS6.1 SDK in XCode5`. Am i right?

You must install iOS6.1 SDK (iphoneos6.1 not simulator iOS6.1) to your XCode first. This question [`Is it possible to install iOS6 SDK on Xcode 5?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5) could help you to install iOS6.1 SDK.

Than you could configure your project using iOS6.1 SDK to build your app like below:

[image: demo-to-change-base-sdk]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to test your app on lower iOS simulators.

go to Xcode - > Preferences - > Downloads

Over here download the desired simulator.

Once you have downloaded and installed it you can test your application on lower iOS versions.