# How to disable iOS 7 interface changes in my app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, ios7

i have an app that perfectly work in iOS 6, and when i update my iPhone to iOS 7 that was still work fine.

Then i update my XCode, and made some minor changes in my app (i did hide 2 UINavigation back bar buttons). After that i update my app (i want to point that i didn't change interface of my app), and when i update it from appStore and launch it on my iPhone there was a completely disaster. Interface objects such as segmented control or UIDatePicker automatically changes for iOS 7 version (style, color), back bar button item change it style, etc.

My question is, how can i force my app to launch on iOS7 with previous (iOS 6) design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing all the native views (switches, date pickers, alerts, action sheets, table views etc) by your own views that replicate iOS 6 appearance.

There are some open-source solutions, too.
However, it will be very hard, don't expect to do it in a few days.

Recommendation? Don't do it. Modify the apperance of your application for iOS 7. The users will expect it. You can't leave your application forever with deprecated appearance. I understand your feelings (my apps look terrible, too) but staying with iOS 6 appearance is not the solution.

Comment: The bad thing is my app approved(!) to appStore and only when i update it from my phone i understand it work terrible (you can even see text typed on controls such as segmented index), and i did not want people to buy thing that cant work properly :(

Answer (score 2):

You can build your app with iOS 6 SDK. But it can be only a temporary solution because Apple will not accept such apps in few month, I think.

Here you can see how to add SDK to Xcode:
[Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)

Comment: I really surprised that i cant button like "revert interface back to iOS 6" or "when launch on iOS7 use old interface", now i guess i'am not the one who face such problem

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, why would Apple want to provide anyone with such a button?

Comment: At now my app not work (user cant select all of cells to tap on it for example), and i have no time to hurry up and fix it now, it will consume couple of days or weeks.. Apple could provide button for developers who did not finish new design, but do want to update they app (for some reason, like bug fixes).

Comment: Apple likes to push developers forward and not let them lag. Sure, it's annoying, but it's part and parcel of being an Apple developer and, overall, for the best for the user that developers keep their apps up to date. Apple *does* have a way to do what you want to do, it's just not a button. Use Xcode 4.6.3 and build against the iOS 6 SDK and not the iOS 7 SDK. There may still be some bugs when running against iOS 7, but it won't be the total UI change that the iOS 7 SDK does.

Comment: BergQuester i'm tried to do this, but unfortunately even when i launch iOS 7 device simulator (when my target is iOS 6.0), i still got new interface. Somehow i need to update it to use iOS 6 elements when it launch on iOS 7 device (i will completely update it later, right now i just don't want users to be upset paying money for junk app which is not working properly).