# Can I build an app that runs on iOS 5.1 and iOS 7 in the respective native look & feel?

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios7, xcode5, ios5.1

I have an app that is targeted mainly for iPads, and I want the users to be able to still use their original iPads (iOS up to 5.1). On the other hand my app should look like a “native” iOS 7 app when run on an iOS 7-device.

When I select `SDKROOT` (Base SDK) as iOS 7 and the deployment target as 6.0, the app runs fine on both systems, showing the respective look & feel. But since I want my app to run on 5.1 also, I set the deployment target to 5.1 (I copied the `iPhoneOS5.1.sdk` to Xcode 5 according to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)). The app then runs on 5.1, 6.0 and 7.0, but it (almost) looks like an iOS 6 app on iOS 7.

This is what I found when dealing with the compiler settings (depending on settings, app runs on what iOS version):

[image: compiler settings table]

So, is this possible: One app, native look & feel on iOS 5.1, iOS 6 and iOS 7?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I ran into an installation/configuration problem by adding the iPhoneOS5.1.sdk to Xcode 5. When I upgraded to Xcode 5.0.2, I did not add that SDK again and now I got what I requested: I can set the Base SDK to 7.0 and Deployment Target to 5.1, then I get native L&F on all iOS versions.

I just have to make sure that I don’t use features introduced later than 5.1 without checking for the OS version (Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on) for how to check the OS version).