# ibtoold(2546,0x11208c000) malloc: *** auto malloc[2546]: error

Tags: compiler-errors, osx-mavericks, xcode4.6.3

I've been getting this error since I upgraded to OSX 10.9 Mavericks. Can anyone tell me what is happening? The app doesn't crash but I get this annoying error everytime I compile. Is there a way to fix this?

```
ibtoold(2546,0x11208c000) malloc: *** auto malloc[2546]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug.Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure


/ibtoold(2546,0x11208c000) malloc: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug.


Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Comment: Any progress on this?  I'm also getting this in Mavericks.  I'm trying to build Growl from source, so I have to stay in Xcode 4.6.x (according to devs).

Comment: I downgraded back to 10.8.5 Mountain Lion. Although Mavericks seem to boot and shutdown a little bit faster. I don't find a real reason to upgrade. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue after upgrading to Mavericks. Just update your Xcode and the errors will go away.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an update for Xcode 4.6.3. Xcode 5 is not an option because the app is designed for iOS 6.

Comment: Maybe xcode 5 can be an option. See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5