# IDEBundleInjection.c: Error 3587 on Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xctest

I am trying to start testing my app, and so I enabled a new test target and a Swift file for the testing. Yet when I try to execute the testing I receive error:

> IDEBundleInjection.c: Error 3587 loading bundle '/Users/fbartolom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/inArrivoHD-ebjdiuuwdpdvchgmpsyqkpvvvyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/inArrivoHD Tests.xctest

By reading some threads I also recovered the XCTest.framework from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/ given it was not available in the selection, after locating it with find on the shell as Spotlight reported no results. Yet in so doing I got some missing symbols in the linking phase, so by reading [How do I migrate from SenTestingKit/OCUnit to XCTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022512/how-do-i-migrate-from-sentestingkit-ocunit-to-xctest) I removed it.
I tried clearing the DerivedData folder several times to no avail. I also put code signing to "Don't Code signing" with changing anything.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to incorrectly importing the MacOS test kit. Once I correctly chose the iOS one everything went in order. Perhaps a better error message would be appreciated.

Comment: Issue for me was code signing that were different for App and Test Bundle

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed the issue by followng the advice at:
http://dunghnt.blogspot.it/2014/12/problems-of-migrating-from-sen-test-to.html

Comment: Unfortunately the process goes further, but not so much, now I am stuck with a failed test with:
Test target inArrivoHD Tests encountered an error (Test session exited(82) without checking in. Executable cannot be loaded for some other reason, such as a problem with a library it depends on or a code signature/entitlements mismatch. Retry after a Clean build. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/sv/mzpy2xgs70qd7zq_36_zb49h0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2015-07-09_15:45:05-BWLkWW.log)

Comment: Basically I get the same errors as before, but I receive in the tests rather than in the linking.

Comment: I tried setting the testing on another project and at first it worked fine. Then I tried deleting and rebuilding everything like I did several times on my project and I got: 
ld: file not found: /Users/fbartolom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/widgetApple-afopvyqjrjvhqudrgjbixhngnqoq/Build/Products/Debug/widgetApple.app/widgetApple
Even while simply compiling, upon deleting the new test it retuned in order.
My project keeps on reporting that weird Injection error.

There must be something to do when setting Testing on an old project I totally miss.