# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PushNotificationManager", referenced from: objc-class-ref in xxxAppDelegate.o

Tags: ios, xcode, pushwoosh

My Problem is:
After upgrade XCode, I found my project can't be build and run on test iPhone. I even check out my old commits in git repository, non of these commit can run on real iPhone which works before. It can build and run on simulator. It also can be archive.

[image]

I have checked other guys question, there is no answer can help me.
I have added all dependent frameworks and static libs for my project and static lib.
[image]

[image]

My Project build setting is:
[image]

My Targets Build Settings is:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your library:

`libPushNotificationManager.a`

Was built using another achitecture, which isn't compatible with armv7s. You need to remove the current library and rebuild it. You can also try to create a new scheme, or change the deployment target from 6.1 to 7+, although the issue is that particular library.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The armv7s cause the problem. I have removed arm7s from Valid Architectures. It works with iPhone 4s. But iPhone 5s got message:Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PushNotificationManager", referenced from:

Comment: In that case you can try using the 6.1 SDK to build your project instead of the latest. Also, [you might want to read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18424373/499581) if you decide to go the route of using the older SDK.