# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException: 'Could not instantiate class named _UITableViewCellSeparatorView'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6.1, xcode5.1

After Xcode Update (5.1) my app crashes when i try to run in iOS 6.x.

I have an app where I have a custom cell and constraints.

Auto layout is unchecked for the xib file. The error I get is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate
>   class named _UITableViewCellSeparatorView'

I only found [one thread about this issue in another forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14691/app-crashes-after-xcode-update), but without a solution, just a test that I've done too and got the same error.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue when I try `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID]`

Comment: At first I thought the issue might have something to do with the SDK problems that happen when upgrading Xcode (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5), but after following the steps again I don't yet have a solution.

Comment: @kraftydevil i've just downgrade my xcode to 5, and same issue! You're right, it's a SDK issue i guess!

Comment: If you're getting the same issue after downgrading then you probably need to put the 6.1 SDK where it belongs. I uninstalled Xcode 5.1, restarted my machine, installed 5.0.2, and then linked the 6.1 SDK and it's working again.

Comment: Now it's working! But, only for xcode 5. Linked 6.1 SDK and that's it! Now, the BIG question, why not in sdk of the xcode 5.1?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was getting the same error after updating to Xcode 5.1.

I was able to get rid of the error by editing the xib for my custom cell.

Under Interface Builder Document in the file inspector, I switched "View as" to "iOS 6.1 and Earlier". I also have "Builds for" set to "iOS 6.0 and Later".

Comment: ooh sounds plausible! I will try this when I'm feeling adventurous enough to update again!

Comment: me too! I'm so close to delivery a project, it's not time to play! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: yep... the "Build for" field is the only one you need to change

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue and "View as" and "Builds For" didn't help me. I changed "Opens in" - "Xcode 5.0" and it helped.

PS Don't forget to remove app from device/simulator, clean project and restart xcode (not sure which way was right, I did all of them)

Answer (score 1):

After installing of Xcode 6.0.1 beta 2, I too was encountered with this problem.

My project has iOS Deployment Target is 6.0

Using answer of @AlexZd, I did next actions:

1. I found all xibs, which will created / displayed at this moment
2. Before my actions this xibs had next standard settings:

[image]

3. So, for every of xibs, selected by me, this settings was changed on next settings:

[image]

Now, check work of it. If this does not works, then do control actions

4.
1) Clean your Xcode project by CMD + SHIFT + K,
2) Clean ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder by hands
3) Remove app from device and then run it via Xcode on this device

This solution was checked by me on 3 iPads with IOS6, IOS7 within IOS8 too. This works perfectly on any of them!