# Migrating project to Xcode 7.2 on OS X El Capitan breaks the build

Tags: xcode7, xib, nslayoutconstraint, osx-elcapitan

I was running OS X Mavericks before with Xcode 7.1, I just updated to OS X El Capitan and Xcode 7.2. My app was launching fine on the simulator and device without any kind of warnings for storyboard. Now I see a bunch of warnings for missing constraints in storyboard and the app crashes with this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutConstraint'

I also tried the solution posted on here : [Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutConstraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095318/could-not-instantiate-class-named-ibnslayoutconstraint)

I couldn't find placeholder="YES" anywhere in xml and my storyboard is too big to actually go through each constraint to see if I by mistake have turned on Placeholder checkbox for any constraint.

I do see the following warnings when viewing xml of the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: @SandyChapman : I'm sorry, I didn't get that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @SandyChapman : http://pastebin.com/NxAdh3q7

Comment: i have the same problem in one of my projects.. can't figure out why .. i reverted back to 7.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in fact not using a Storyboard, but a Xib. In your file you'll find sections such as this:

```
<mask key="constraints">
    <exclude reference="6fq-cy-xp8"/>
</mask>
```

You'll want to open your `.xib` as "Source Code" and remove these so that the constraints become `installed`.

Comment: That did work! I don't understand whether they were always there or whether they got added while migration. Do you know if anything can be done in IB to ensure it doesn't happen again?

Comment: Usually this doesn't happen unless you check the tick box in IB to disable the "installed" state.

Answer (score 1):

Select Storyboard Disable Size class resolve my problem. Hope this will help you! Thanks
After build your project you can again enable size class.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that basically the same thing as saying, "destroy your user interface and then re-build it"? Apps with a large UI would lose almost all of their size class configuration by disabling size classes. This work-around should really only be considered a "nuclear" option as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

well mainly make sure that when you’re using IB to check that you don’t have any constraints with the “**installed**” checkbox checked if the **view** they belong to is “**not installed**”. Xcode 7.1 doesn’t even give a warning about this, but 7.2  causes a crash

Comment: For each of the constraint on the storyboard, at least one "installed" checkbox is checked by default. I don't know how that works or what different checkboxes mean but they seem to not cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

`Disable` `AutoLayout` on your storyboard. This should fix your problem.