# why Xcode 7.2 crash 'Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutConstraint'?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode7.1, xcode7.2

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate
>   class named IBNSLayoutConstraint'

I just update Xcode to 7.2 then i start to check is everything alright. but I have this error and it crashes. I dig this problem, everybody said that "Make sure you don't have any constraints installed for views that aren't installed." but I don't have any uninstalled constrains. and I don't have any NSLayoutConstraint outlets.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutConstraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095318/could-not-instantiate-class-named-ibnslayoutconstraint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably using **InterfaceBuilder Storyboard** for localization. You should also consider them and remove inactive constraits inside them or use **Localizable Strings** for localization.

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24162960/1017153) answer.

[image: Storyyboard localization section]

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I missed that. I have two storyboard. and i just change some constraints only one. Thanks for your answer. It helps me solve this problem.

Answer (score 24):

Select Storyboard Disable Size class resolve my problem. Hope this will help you! Thanks
After build your project you can again enable size class.

[image]

Comment: Did you also then re-enable size classes? For most apps, you absolutely SHOULD be using size classes, so keeping this turned off is probably either the wrong answer or indicative of a bug that should be filed.

Comment: You are a life saver, but i wonder if this occurs at random times and this is the solution for it, do we have to apply this solution to every storyboard before sending to store ?

Comment: @DanielJ for me it was fine after I turned size classes back on; definitely seems to be a bug though

Comment: Disabling & running fixed the problem.  I was then able to re-Enable size classes, and the problem stayed fixed.

Comment: This removes (disabling and re-enabling) some `<constraint>` entries from the storyboard xml, but couldn't find any negative effect, app continues working normally.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I had "padView" that was not installed in any/any size class and was installed in regular/regular size class, but it's subviews were installed in all size classes.

[image]

"PadView" settings:

[image]

"PadView" subviews settings:

[image]

When I changed "PadView" subviews installation settings to the same as "PadView" settings my problem was resolved.

[image]

Comment: Your answer and @Kayron Cabral's answer below seem to point to the same problem. Both your solutions are equivalent, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

I had a view deactivated (not installed) in my main view in IB. I deleted it and also deleted all the constraints without reference to IB. And worked for me.

[image: View deactivated]

[image: Attributes inspector]

Comment: Your answer and @Evgeny Mikhaylov's answer below seem to point to the same problem. Both your solutions are equivalent, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I have an app that sets custom size classes for iPad so app recognizes Portrait and Landscape orientations as Regular/Compact and Compact/Regular traits.

So, when I had one view installed only as both R/C Installed and C/R Installed, I got crash: 'Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutConstraint' when I upgraded to 7.2 final.

Fix is very simple: to add view install for Any/Any: "Installed"

By comparing Storyboard source it appears that this line was removed after fixing:

// y4d-LA-PwQ is view specific ID

Comment: Yes. You are right. generally I use this method when storyboards elements are not installed. it is exactly easiest way to install all element in storyboard. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Also, you can up vote if that helped any.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to solve without applying the hackery mentioned in the above answer. Switch your IB to any/any and look through the subviews of each topview. If you find a super view that is not installed and subview of it installed, disable this installed subview in any/any so that the super view and the subviews will have same status of installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking "Use Size Classes":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did have a similar issue in where I received a "Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutContraint" error when one of my apps loaded my XIBs. It ended up being one of my contraints had a check mark on it's properties. It was something like "Remove from Build". I unchecked it and resolved my error. I don't think this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John. But I checked all constarints placeholder. All of them are unselected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the conflicting constraint and add it again ;)