# Keep getting linker errors on Xcode 5.1 despite reverting to 32bit architectures only

Tags: ios, xcode5.1, arm64

since I updated to Xcode 5.1, which changes the standard architectures to also include `arm64`, I keep getting the following error from the linker:

```
0  0x109157f93  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x1091faed4  ld::passes::stubs::Pass::makeStub(ld::Atom const&, bool) + 0
2  0x1091fb5f7  ld::passes::stubs::Pass::process(ld::Internal&) + 497
3  0x1091fbc07  ld::passes::stubs::doPass(Options const&, ld::Internal&) + 111
4  0x109158b50  main + 772
5  0x7fff8568b5fd  start + 1
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/MyApp-2014-02-19-175731.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (target != NULL), function stubableFixup, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-236.3/src/ld/passes/stubs/stubs.cpp, line 126.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

given the fact that I use third party libraries which are compiled only for armv7, I tried to set the Architectures and Valid Architectures options to only include armv7, in both the Project's and the target's build settings, but I keep getting the error, even after cleaning... any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution (a workaround - rather), in my case, was to disable the `Dead Code Stripping` functionality in the Linking section of the Build Settings.

There seems to be a bug in Xcode 5.1 regarding this feature and the `Link Time Optimization` one (which I already had set to **NO**).

More info can be found here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/950372#950372

**EDIT (2014-04-18):**

The problem seems to be solved as of Xcode 5.1.1, as turning the `Dead Code Stripping` flag back to Yes no longer results in the linking error.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error message for one of my apps and the only thing that fixed it for me was to change Link-Time Optimizations to No.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same error,

What you want to do is go to project build settings, and set 'Build Active Architecture Only' to **NO** for Debug as well as Release. . .

This would get you going :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I already had that flag set to NO, both in the Project's and in the Target's build settings!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't too far afield of your question, but it's worth noting that you can keep old SDKs around to use after upgrading Xcode. It's not a bad idea to backup the contents of the following folders before an upgrade:

```
$(xcode-select --print-path)/Platforms/*/Developer/SDKs
```

The old SDKs can be copied back in after the upgrade. Obviously, **it's better to use the latest SDK whenever possible**, but sometimes deadlines and development realities make it necessary to continue with a working SDK until code can be re-worked.

This process can also be performed semi-automatically. Simply install the latest Xcode version in a new location (keeping the old version untouched) and link the existing SDKs with the following script:

```
platforms_path="$1/Contents/Developer/Platforms";
if [ -d $platforms_path ]; then
    for platform in `ls $platforms_path`
    do
        sudo ln -sf $platforms_path/$platform/Developer/SDKs/* $(xcode-select --print-path)/Platforms/$platform/Developer/SDKs;
    done;
fi;
```

You just need to supply it with the path to the old `.app`:

```
./xcode.sh /Applications/Xcode-463.app
```

More information in this question:

- [Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5/20108257#20108257)

You can find old versions of Xcode here:

- https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

Comment: thank you for the answer, this is very instructive, even if not really a solution to the base problem!