# XCode 5.1 clang++ error Assertion failed: (target != NULL), function stubableFixup

Tags: xcode, ld, clang++, xcode5.1

I have recently updated XCode from 5.0 to 5.1.
The same project that compiled successfully with XCode 5.0 now isn't compiling at all with 5.1

The error happens during the linking phase. Here's the error:

`0  0x103303f93  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x1033a6ed4  ld::passes::stubs::Pass::makeStub(ld::Atom const&, bool) + 0
2  0x1033a75f7  ld::passes::stubs::Pass::process(ld::Internal&) + 497
3  0x1033a7c07  ld::passes::stubs::doPass(Options const&, ld::Internal&) + 111
4  0x103304b50  main + 772
5  0x7fff8fa2f5fd  start + 1
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/Crumbee-2014-02-19-123506.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (target != NULL), function stubableFixup, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-236.3/src/ld/passes/stubs/stubs.cpp, line 126.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have been googling for this error but the only result is the source code of the stubs.cpp file from Apple Open Source repo. 
Is there anyone who's familiar with the linker and the latest changes of XCode that can help me?

I have the snapshot mentioned by the message up there handy, in case anyone knows what to do with it to figure something out.

Comment: Ciao! We are in the same situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513294/keep-getting-linker-errors-on-xcode-5-1-despite-reverting-to-32bit-architectures

Comment: @micamoita Sebastien's answer is what did the trick for me. I figured it out by trial and error switching linking flags around during the night :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to turn off link time optimizations in the build settings? It fixed the problem for me.