# How can I install the new iOS SDK on Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, itunes

How can I install the new iOS SDK on Xcode 5 to be able to compile applications for the new iOS on Xcode 5? I've tried to use iTunes to transfer compiled applications to the device. But it doesn't work any more.

**Edit**

I've tried to copy SDK folders from xCode 6 to xCode 5 as described on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18423896/2970947). But, it doesn't work because of an issue with `ibtool` during compilation process

Comment: First, it's not a duplicate of the linked question. I've tried to copy SDK folders from xCode 6 to xCode 5 as described on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5?rq=1 But it doesn't work because of issue with `ibtool` during compilation process.

Comment: Don't modify the Xcode app bundle.  You can't do what you're asking.  Why can't you use the Xcode 6 beta?

Comment: How about using multiple versions? (I have three Xcode versions, 4.4.1, 5.1.1 and 6beta)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you are trying iOS8 you can't use anything less than Xcode 6 beta.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334033/1255674).

If you're using Mavericks and want to continue using Xcode 5, do these steps:

- Rename *Xcode.app* to *Xcode 5.app*
- Download and copy Xcode 6 to Applications-Folder, and rename it to
  *Xcode 6.app*
- and...

Execute this command in Terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode\ 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ \(12A365\)/ /Applications/Xcode\ 5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ \(12A365\)
```