# Xcode 5 not detecting iPhone running iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, ios8

I have an iPhone with iOS 8 installed on it, but when I connect it to Xcode 5.1, it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: for ios8 you need to install xcode6

Comment: xcode 6 (not beta) is available now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the Xcode 6 Beta. It's available in the iOS Developer Center, where you downloaded the iOS 8 Beta.

Comment: If you would rather not use Beta software or upgrade your project to Xcode 6, you can continue using Xcode 5 for development and test on an iOS 8 device.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 30):

As with the other answers, it seemed fairly random whether or not my iOS 8 device was being picked up by Xcode 5.1.  It appears that it works if you have the iOS 8 device plugged in **before** you start Xcode 5.1.  When you do that, you will get a screen indicating the symbols are being processed:

[image: Xcode 5.1 Screenshot]

After this completes, the device is selectable.  I am pretty sure this needs to be performed with each new beta.  That might explain why it appears to suddenly stop working.

If this isn't working for you, make sure you have the latest Xcode 6 Beta to match the iOS 8 Beta version, and connect the device while Xcode 6 is running.  The same "Processing Symbol" files process will occur and then Xcode 5.1 seems to work.

Comment: Wow. I couldn't figure out how it worked for me before. Thanks for documenting that out. Having Xcode 6 open when connecting was the key for me.

Answer (score 7):

the only decent way to make it work is to create a symbolic link to a folder that contains binary for iOS8. You can make fool Xcode 5.1 saying "yes, iOS 8 is ok." via a symlink:

In my case I have Xcode 5.1 on Mavericks HD, and Xcode 6.0 beta 4 on Yosemite HD.

I did:

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ (12A4331d)     /Volumes/MAVERICKS/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ (12A4331d)

and Xcode 5.1 did work with my iOS8 iphone.

(note the space before /Volumes/MAVER... )

PS: for every beta, I have to patch again... :(

Comment: If you're using Mavericks, and you can rename _Xcode.app_ to _Xcode 5.app_, install Xcode 6 as _Xcode 6.app_ and execute this command in Terminal: `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode\ 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ \(12A365\)/ /Applications/Xcode\ 5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ \(12A365\)`

Answer (score 2):

I have connected my iPhone with iOS 8 installed to Xcode 5.1.**First time it doesn't recognize.but when i unplugged device and connect again , Device Recognized.**
I dont know the reason Anyway i am sure that you can also connect your IOS8 installed device to Xcode5.1 ....

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Xcode 5 to build on an iOS 8 device just fine. Now all of a sudden, it won't let me anymore.

Comment: You need Xcode 6 to detect the iPhone running iOS 8.

Comment: This should be a comment, it does not provide any new information or answer the question.

Comment: You're right. I don't know why I did that. Brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

first use xcode6 build on your iPhone5s. 
second open xcode 5 ,unpluge device and connect again.
then device recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Open xcode 6 and wait until device is recognised. When done, close xcode 6 and open xcode 5.1 and your device is going to be automatically recognised.

That way you can run your application on a device with iOS 8 with the old xcode.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Easiest and works for me. Just go to another mac with xcode 6, plug it in, and wait for the symbols stuff to finish. Then the phone will work on your xcode 5.