# UIAlertController if iOS 8, otherwise UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview, ios8, uialertcontroller

I want to conform to the UIAlertController used in iOS 8 since UIAlertView is now deprecated. Is there a way that I can use this without breaking support for iOS 7? Is there some kind of if condition I can do to check for iOS 8 otherwise do something else for iOS 7 support?

Comment: FYI - Since your Deployment Target is iOS 7 (or earlier), you can just use `UIAlertView`. This will keep your code a lot simpler.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Swift had a respondsToSelector... Also, the UIAlertView is screwed up in ios8, it doesn't scroll where as it does in ios 7, which is why I want to try to use both

Comment: The scroll doesn't work on the UIAlertController either

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView/UIAlertController iOS 7 and iOS 8 compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111011/uialertview-uialertcontroller-ios-7-and-ios-8-compatibility)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the answer of **Erwan** (below my answer) as I see it is the best.

--

You can check the iOS version to use appropriate control like this:

```
if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
    // use UIAlertView
}
else {
    // use UIAlertController
}
```

Comment: I have posted what I think is a better approach below, checking if the class exists rather than checking the version of the OS

Comment: This is a fragile way to perform this check. In fact Apple recommends against these kind of checks. The answer by Erwan is the correct answer.

Comment: One should never check against version numbers in code, this is very bad practice. As squarefrog points out @Erwan has the better solution, always check against capabilities/features.

Comment: As noted, conditional eval of [UIAlertController class] is the preferred strategy.  If checking the version for the OS is necessary, the preferred convention is to compare NSFoundationVersionNumber -- detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW3)

Answer (score 99):

I think a much better way to check if a class exists (since iOS 4.2) is:

```
if([ClassToBeChecked class]) {

   // use it

} else {

  // use alternative

}
```

In your case, that would be:

```
if ([UIAlertController class]) {
   // use UIAlertController

} else {
  // use UIAlertView

}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but when I'm running XCode 5, my code will not compile. How do I verify that this actually works on iOS7?

Comment: This should definitely work on iOs7 and Xcode5. Feel free to post your code here. Something must be wrong

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Always check for class/feature/constant/function existence instead of checking the iOS version.

Comment: Thanks @VilémKurz but how do you mark an answer as correct?

Comment: it might depend on whether you've got the ios 8 SDK. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015490/how-can-i-install-the-new-ios-sdk-on-xcode-5

Comment: How to do it on Swift?

Comment: @mitrenegade this approach prevents you from checking the iOS version. It will work on any iOS after 4.2

Comment: Yes, but if someone is compiling code that was written by someone with the ios 8 sdk, but they are now using the ios 7 sdk on xcode 5, the code will not compile. That's the problem @huey is getting because he's compiling on xcode 5, UIAlertController will not be recognized. If you are using the most recent SDK, your answer is the correct one because when a phone running ios7 runs your app built with ios8, it will just return nil on [UIAlertController class].

Comment: @mitrenegade but if he is compiling with iOS7 on Xcode 5, the rest of the code will not compile anyway. What's the point of testing if the version allows to use this class if you compile it with a version that does not know the class

Comment: right, so @huey shouldn't try to compile on xcode 5. he needs to use xcode 6 and use your code to prevent calling UIAlertController if a device uses ios7. my comment was meant to point out that the reason it's not compiling is that the class is not available on the ios 7 sdk. however, your first response said that it will work on ios7 and xcode 5, which is not true if that class is not available.

Comment: @huey can use Xcode 6 to build and run on iOS7 simulator to confirm his code runs on iOS7. He doesn't need Xcode5 to do that.

Comment: My practice is to consult the Developer Library and code accordingly. For example, UIActionSheet is deprecated in favor of UIAlertController in iOS 8, but [UIActionSheet class] will return true in iOS 8. If in doubt, read the library to consult the API, and check the OS version and the existence of the class in the code for best practice (defensive programming).

Answer (score 12):

Objective C (as mentioned above)

```
if ([UIAlertController class]) {
    // use UIAlertController

} else {
    // use UIAlertView

}
```

Swift

```
if objc_getClass("UIAlertController") == nil  {
       // use UIAlertView 

} else {
  // use UIAlertController

}
```

Don't use `if NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") == nil` It is not working because the signature for this method is `func NSClassFromString(_ aClassName: String!) -> AnyClass!`

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned - always check whether a feature exists. I believe the safest approach is following:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController")) {
    // use UIAlertController
} else {
    // use UIAlertView
}
```

With the obvious risk of entering a class name with a typo. :)

From documentation of **NClassFromString**:

> [Returns] The class object named by aClassName, or nil if no class by that name is currently loaded. If aClassName is nil, returns nil.
>
> Availability iOS (2.0 and later)

Comment: This code snippet translated into Swift works correctly on the iOS simulator using iOS 7.1 and 8.2, but if you test on a real device using iOS 7.1, you will unfortunately notice that you will never pass through the else part of the code snippet. So this snippet of code is unstable and I would not recommend using it on production.

Comment: alino-91 comment is true. Use objc_getClass instead

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for checking iOS version in Swift**

```
switch (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare("8.0.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch)) {
    case .OrderedAscending:
       println("iOS < 8.0")

    case .OrderedSame, .OrderedDescending:
       println("iOS >= 8.0")
}
```

Con of this solution: it is simply bad practice to check against OS version numbers, whichever way you do it. One should never hard code dependencies in this way, always check for features, capabilities or the existence of a class. Consider this; Apple may release a backwards compatible version of a class, if they did then the code you suggest would never use it as your logic looks for an OS version number and NOT the existence of the class.

([Source of this information](http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/))

**Solution for checking the class' existence in Swift**

```
if (objc_getClass("UIAlertController") == nil) {
   // iOS 7
} else {
   // iOS 8+
}
```

Do not use `if (NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") == nil)` because it works correctly on the iOS simulator using iOS 7.1 and 8.2, but if you test on a real device using iOS 7.1, you will unfortunately notice that you will never pass through the else part of the code snippet.

Comment: "Do not use if (NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") == nil) because it works correctly on the iOS simulator using iOS 7.1 and 8.2, but if you test on a real device using iOS 7.1, you will unfortunately notice that you will never pass through the else part of the code snippet." That is true. I wish I read this before.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Above ios 8.0
float os_version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (os_version >= 8.000000)
{
   　　　//Use UIAlertController    
}
else
{
     //UIAlertView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create simple `utility function` to reduce code**

**CODE :**

```
// pass minimum required iOS version
BOOL isOSSupported(NSString *minRequiredVersion)
{
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    BOOL isOSSupported = ([currSysVer compare:minRequiredVersion options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) && 
                                  ![currSysVer isEqualToString:@"Unknown"];
    return isOSSupported;
}
```

**USE :**

```
if(isOSSupported("8.0")
{
// Code for iOS8 and above
}
else
{
// Code for iOS7 and below
}
```

---

**Or Use system constant `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1` as below**

```
if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
{
   // Code for iOS8 and above
}
else
{
   // Code for iOS7 and below
}
```

for more options [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version)

Comment: There is no need of -1 :)), who did this please share your thought to others

Comment: Bad practice, never check against version numbers. Always check against capabilities/features.

Comment: @SHaKie then in which case its good to use constant NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 provided by apple

Comment: The best practice is to check if the class exists as on my answer posted above. For methods you could also check that the class responds to @selector(yourMethod)

Comment: @Jageen I'm afraid not. It is simply bad practice to check against OS version numbers, whichever way you do it. One should never hard code dependencies in this way, always check for features, capabilities or the existence of a class. Consider this; Apple may release a backwards compatible version of a class, if they did then the code you suggest would never use it as your logic looks for an OS version number and NOT the existence of the class.

Answer (score 1):

I have created very simple wrapper in Objective-C, that supports both - old iOS UIAlertView and new one `UIAlertViewController`

https://github.com/MartinPerry/UIAlert/

It also brings the new action blocks usage to old `UIAlertView`

Sample:

```
MyAlertMessage * a = [[MyAlertMessage alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" WithMessage:@"World"];

[a addButton:BUTTON_OK WithTitle:@"OK" WithAction:^(void *action) { 
  NSLog(@"Button OK at index 0 click"); 
}];

[a addButton:BUTTON_CANCEL WithTitle:@"Cancel" WithAction:^(void *action) {
  NSLog(@"Button Cancel at index 1 click"); 
}];

[a show];
```

Comment: Does this handle multiple alerts?

Answer (score 1):

I have written one class that wrap the UIAlertView and use UIAlertController. For the programmer is transparently hence is sufficient import this classes in the project. The utility of this classes is when in a old project there are more UIAlertView to change. Link: https://github.com/kennymuse/UIAlertView

Answer (score 0):

### Method one

by ios system version check

```
#define iOSVersionLessThan(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
// below ios8 ,create UIAlertView
if(iOSVersionLessThan(@"7.0")){
     // todo

// ios8 and above ,UIActionController avaliable
}else{
    // todo
}
```

### Method two

by system feature detect

```
// create UIActionController 
if([UIActionController class]){
    // todo
// create UIAlertView
}else{
    // todo
}
```

But,there's a third lib named [PSTAlertController](https://github.com/steipete/PSTAlertController) that deal with backwards compatible to iOS 7 of UIActionSheet and UIAlertView.

### ref to

- [Supporting Multiple Versions of iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW24)
- [Supporting iOS 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html)
- [Supporting Multiple iOS Versions and Devices](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It works fine for both iOS 8 and below version.

```
if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                             {

                             }];
[alertVC addAction:cancelAction];

[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController] presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:^{

}];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```