# Submitting an app update using the iOS6 SDK

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, ios8, app-store

I have inherited an app that is built against the iOS6 SDK. There are numerous UI bugs when building against the iOS7 or 8 SDKs.

I understand that [as of Feb 1, 2014 Apple is no longer accepting *submissions*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18424373/1017700) for apps that are built against iOS6.

My question is, does this rule include *updates* or is the rule just for brand new apps?

I will probably update the app to the latest SDK, but still currently weighing up my options.

Comment: An update is a submission. It must follow those same rules. iOS 7 support, retina support, iPhone 5 support. Soon (a few months) it will require iPhone 6/6+ support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The announcement text was:

> Starting February 1, **new apps and app updates** submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be
>   optimized for iOS 7. Learn more about preparing your apps by reviewing
>   the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

So unfortunately you'll have to update the app in order to submit any changes.