# Install xcode 4 on OS X Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I need to install old version of Xcode on Yosemite. Xcode 5 installed perfectly but I am facing problem with Xcode 4. It crashes, these are the errors:

```
Process:               Xcode [4341]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               4.6.3 (2068)
Build Info:            IDEApplication-2068000000000000~3
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [4341]
User ID:               501

OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        5F18251C-5B88-768B-7023-12B7B510FD63


Time Awake Since Boot: 13000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H1503
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'delegateClass' of extension 'Xcode.OrganizerSource.ArchivedApplications.ArchiveListContextualMenu' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEArchivedApplicationsViewer'
UserInfo: {
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x4016afbe0 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiPhoneSupport, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport\U201d at path \U201c/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x40033a480 \"The bundle \U201cIDEiPhoneSupport\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";
}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff97fe3634 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff8db0c6de objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x0000000106012e16 -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] (in DVTFoundation)
```

ect....

Comment: Why install Xcode 4 ?

Comment: Because of reasons...

Comment: JK, Because my app do not run well on xcode 6, very buggy and I do not have time to make the adjustment to iOS 7,8. So I need a shortcut.

Comment: You could use a virtual machine with an older OS X version for such "shortcuts".

Comment: @Dim, it cannot be any good reason to do so, it is pointless to swim against the tide – install Xcode 5.1.1+.

Comment: @holex: It's pointless to tell other developers how to do their work. For example, maybe fixing the iOS 7 problems might result in several man-days of work but he just needs to push out a simple fix _now_.

Comment: @DarkDust, what I meant, pointless to use any older Xcode version than 5.1.1+, but the application cannot be submitted to the AppStore with those version of Xcode. on other hand, I don't care about other developers. :)

Comment: One good reason to install Xcode 4 on Yosemite is it's the latest version well supported by Cocotron.  From what I've read, people have gotten Cocotron to work sort of with Xcode 5 but there are problems.

Comment: @Holex - Xcode 5 does not work with an iPad running iOS 5.1.1. iOS 5.1.1 is the last update Apple provided for first generations iPads; and you need to use Xcode 4.6.

Comment: @jww, even worse. especially, that time when Xcode7 is the latest version.

Comment: @Holex - yep... but it does not change the fact my (and others) early iPads still exist, and they are still used. Apple makes sure iTunes actually works so store purchases can be made...

Comment: @jww, yes, that is true, but no one targets application to iOS5 anymore (completely pointless as iOS7-6-5-4-3 is __8%__ altogether), it is always recommended to follow the Apple's way to support the last two major iOS versions only (iOS8+ runs on __92%__ of devices at this very moment), according to the statistics that will be about 97% vs 3% at in few months time... there is no business interest in the rest 3% segment, those are not your future clients, no matter which your business is.

Comment: @holex - I still use my iPad. I'm a part time developer, and I have to jump through extraordinary hoops to target it. I'm not throwing away expensive hardware just because Apple does not feel like supporting it, or they want to increase sales at my expense. I'm not an Apple shareholder.

Comment: @jww, I have an iPad2 too, I still use it too, but when a company makes a business plan of developing an app, the balance between the profit and the development cost/time is critical and pretty much based on pure math, not emotions; like if they can earn $X after they invested $Y, they won't go for a plan earning $1.02X while they need to invest $1.5Y for supporting a system for 3% of potential users, they will sacrifice those users instead, in the most of the cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to run Xcode 4, I suggest you run Xcode 5 or 6 but [install the iOS 6 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5) so you can compile your iOS 6 SDK app on Xcode 5 or 6.

Be aware that [Apple will not accept any app submission with SDK < 8](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a) after February 2015. Apps also need to be 64-bit as well (of course, you're still allowed to ship a dual 32-bit/64-bit app).

Comment: This does not really answer the question; its mostly [bikeshedding](http://bikeshed.com/) and would probably be better left as a comment. Xcode 5 or 6 does not work with an iPad running iOS 5.1.1. iOS 5.1.1 is the last update Apple provided to its first generation iPads; and you need to use Xcode 4.6.

Comment: @jww: You seem to confuse _Xcode_ and its _SDK_. You can use a recent Xcode to target an old iOS device just fine. Usually it's not a problem using a recent SDK as well when targeting an older device, but in the OP's case, the recent SDK of Xcode 6 was causing him trouble because he hadn't made adjustments for iOS 7 yet (see his comments). To solve this, all he needed was the iOS 6 SDK, which you can install and use in more recent versions of Xcode as well. So you _don't_ need to use Xcode 4.6 to target an iPad with iOS 5.1. We also did this for a long time to target OS X 10.4, for example.

Comment: Also, [bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality) is when you're discussing an unimportant detail in an otherwise complex issue. That's not what happened here: after the OP refined his requirements in the comments, I merely suggested another approach that solved his problem.

Comment: *"You can use a recent Xcode to target an old iOS device just fine...."* - I don't believe that's true. As a matter of fact, I have two iPad 1's and an iPad 2 that Xcode can't manage because Apple implicitly deemed them obsolete by fiat. If I keep the down level Macs around with the down level Xcodes, [then I can't get security updates for the Macs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/180396/83961) because Apple implicitly deemed the OS obsolete by fiat.

Comment: @jww: I just built an app with Xcode 7 (no legacy SDK installed, just iOS 9 SDK) and deployed and debugged it on an iPad 2 running iOS 6.1. I don't have a device with an older iOS around at the moment, so maybe there is a limit. But you _can_ deploy to devices running old iOS versions. We do it daily, for years!

Comment: @DarkDust - *"I just built an app with Xcode 7 ... and deployed and debugged it on an iPad 2 running iOS 6.1"* - out of curiosity, were you able to provision the iPads (i.e., *Use for Development*), or were they previously provisioned? Related, see this problem I am experiencing: [What PKI Authorities are trusted by OS after a Jailbreak and Cydia install?](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/339303/what-pki-authorities-are-trusted-by-os-after-a-jailbreak-and-cydia-install).

Comment: Using a Jailbroken device is not my first choice. I'm trying to use Jailbroken devices because I can't get modern Xcode to provision the devices due to the tangled requirements Apple has created. The Xcode 4.6.3 launch crash on OS X 10.8.5 complicates matters, but I don't expect Apple to fix it.

Comment: They are already provisioned and none of them is jailbroken. But this has already grown into a discussion that deviates from the original question and problem. If you have issues working with old devices on a recent Xcode, please ask a new question as it should work. Bottomline is: most likely you don't need Xcode 4; OP didn't, for example, and we didn't either.

Comment: @DarkDust - *"f you have issues working with old devices on a recent Xcode, please ask a new question as it should work..."* - fair enough. Here's the next question: [How to perform mobile device provisioning from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32954172).